# Is there any way to use curl commands to train a time series Google AutoML Tables model?

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, time-series, google-cloud-automl

The JSON file given below is the request.json used to train a classification or regression models using Google AutoML Tables.

```
{
  "datasetId": "dataset-id",
  "displayName": "model-display-name",
  "tablesModelMetadata": {
    "trainBudgetMilliNodeHours": "train-budget-milli-node-hours",
    "optimizationObjective": "optimization-objective",
    "targetColumnSpec": {
      "name": "projects/project-id/locations/location/datasets/dataset-id/tableSpecs/table-id/columnSpecs/target-column-id"
    }
  },
}
```

I need to train a time series model using curl commands by providing the "Time Series Identifier" column and "Forecast Horizon" in the json file. So my ideal request file would be

```
{
  "datasetId": "dataset-id",
  "displayName": "model-display-name",
  "tablesModelMetadata": {
    "trainBudgetMilliNodeHours": "train-budget-milli-node-hours",
    "optimizationObjective": "optimization-objective",
    "forecastHorizon": "horizon",
    "timeseriesIdentifier":"column-id",
    "targetColumnSpec": {
      "name": "projects/project-id/locations/location/datasets/dataset-id/tableSpecs/table-id/columnSpecs/target-column-id"
    }
  },
}
```

So that I can pass the request.json file given above using the command

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://endpoint/v1beta1/projects/project-id/locations/location/models/
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment Cloud Auto ML Tables provides [predictions](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/problem-types) for either regression or classification problems.

You should consider BigQuery ML to create a model statement for [time series models](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-time-series#training_a_time_series_model_to_forecast_a_single_time-series), you can use the the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/models#trainingoptions) to pass the parameters "timeSeriesIdColumn" and "horizon" in your  curl command.

JSON representation

```
{
  "trainingOptions": {
    {
     "maxIterations": string,
     "lossType": enum (LossType),
     "learnRate": number,
     "l1Regularization": number,
     "l2Regularization": number,
     "minRelativeProgress": number,
     "warmStart": boolean,
     "earlyStop": boolean,
     "inputLabelColumns": [
       string
     ],
     "dataSplitMethod": enum (DataSplitMethod),
     "dataSplitEvalFraction": number,
     "dataSplitColumn": string,
     "learnRateStrategy": enum (LearnRateStrategy),
     "initialLearnRate": number,
     "labelClassWeights": {
       string: number,
       ...
     },
     "userColumn": string,
     "itemColumn": string,
     "distanceType": enum (DistanceType),
     "numClusters": string,
     "modelUri": string,
     "optimizationStrategy": enum (OptimizationStrategy),
     "hiddenUnits": [
       string
     ],
     "batchSize": string,
     "dropout": number,
     "maxTreeDepth": string,
     "subsample": number,
     "minSplitLoss": number,
     "numFactors": string,
     "feedbackType": enum (FeedbackType),
     "walsAlpha": number,
     "kmeansInitializationMethod": enum (KmeansInitializationMethod),
     "kmeansInitializationColumn": string,
     "timeSeriesTimestampColumn": string,
     "timeSeriesDataColumn": string,
     "autoArima": boolean,
     "nonSeasonalOrder": {
       object (ArimaOrder)
     },
     "dataFrequency": enum (DataFrequency),
     "includeDrift": boolean,
     "holidayRegion": enum (HolidayRegion),
     "timeSeriesIdColumn": string,
     "horizon": string,
     "preserveInputStructs": boolean,
     "autoArimaMaxOrder": string
   }
     },
  "startTime": string,
  "results": [
    {
      object (IterationResult)
    }
  ],
  "evaluationMetrics": {
    object (EvaluationMetrics)
  },
  "dataSplitResult": {
    object (DataSplitResult)
  }
}
```

Curl command:

```
curl \
  'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/model/YOUR_MODEL?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  -d @request.json \ \
  --compressed
```